# does using copy content harmful for my website's seo?

Tags: content, copyright

I am using copy contents from another similar websites but I always change the title a bit.But I want to know is this way good for my website that get result by google or not?!
Do I get visitors from google search or not?!

Answer (score -3):

I don`t like to copy content but if you must do this for any reason follow this steps:

You must do some fresh content beside this.

Ex: 10 copy and 1 fresh. this will be enough but my advice for more protect and more improve at google, Do the next steps also:

**Convert it to common content:**

Do some changes in content like add fresh tow lines at top and bottom of content.

Add some good internal links to get good User experience to more protect.

Comment: This doesn't sound like good advice to me.  I'd only recommend copying content with the permission of the content owner (content syndication).   I'd recommend much more fresh content compared to duplicated content.  At least a 50/50 ratio, but ideal more like 80% fresh content.  Google's shingle algorithm can detect as little as seven words that are duplicated from another source.   Just adding a couple lines at the top and the bottom is not enough to distinguish a copy from the original.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I added link of source and the reason about I have to copy content is that I don't have many employers to make custom content because it takes too much money and for now just can being update my website then maybe in future I have some guys to make custom and fresh content